# adding different columns in same table usin inner join in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to make a report of time entry of particular projects. I tried below query.

Table1: Projects

```
id   | Name
------------
1    |  A
2    |  B
```

Table2: EmployeeTimeEntry

```
proj | activity  |time
----------------------
1    | coding    | 5
2    | coding    | 2
1    | testing   | 2
1    | coding    | 2
```

My desired Outpput for proj A:

```
proj  | TotalDur  | activity | Activitytime
--------------------------------------------
A     |  9        | coding   |  7
A     |  9        | testing  |  2
```

My Query :

```
$query = "SELECT        
    name  as 'Proj',        
    TimeEntry.Total as 'TotalDur',
    ATimeEntry.ADetails as 'activity',
    ATimeEntry.ATotal as 'Activitytime'             
    FROM Projects pr

    INNER JOIN(SELECT project,SUM(time) as Total from EmployeeTimeEntry group by project ) TimeEntry on pr.id = TimeEntry.project
    INNER JOIN(SELECT project,details as ADetails,SUM(time) as ATotal from EmployeeTimeEntry where id = pr.id group by details ) ATimeEntry on pr.id = TimeEntry.project";
```

But i got output as

```
proj  | TotalDur  | activity | Activitytime
--------------------------------------------
A     |  9        | coding   |  9
A     |  9        | testing  |  2
```

All activity times for all projects get added .
 I use combobo to select which projects to show the report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are over complicating it

```
select
p.name as Proj,
x.TotalDur,
et.activity,
sum(et.time) as Activitytime
from Projects p
join (
   select proj, sum(time) as TotalDur from EmployeeTimeEntry group by proj
)x on x.proj = p.id
join EmployeeTimeEntry et on et.proj = p.id
where p.name = 'A'
group by p.name,et.activity
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/52da3/2)**

Comment: $query = "select
p.name as Proj,
x.TotalDur,
et.details,
SUM(et.date_end) as Activitytime
from Projects p
join (
   select project, SUM(date_end) as TotalDur from EmployeeTimeEntry group by project
)x on x.project = p.id
join EmployeeTimeEntry et on et.project = p.id
where p.name = 'Project1'
group by p.name,et.details ";   my query is like this, but nothing shows in final report.

Comment: My query is working fine with SQLFiddle..may be im missing something in my code.

Comment: Not quite understand what you said .

Comment: can we assign variable to where clause instead of string like   where p.id = et.proj,  because im sending this query as a string to another function. i use this same query for displaying all projects. (i.e proj  A and proj B).

Comment: Yes you can use `where p.name = 'A'` to accept the variable name. This will filter out the result as per the input value.

Comment: if i use where p.name = et.proj ,  it shows error as Unknown column 'et.proj' in 'where clause

Comment: No thats wrong `where p.name = et.projcode` the where condition I added since your expected out put is only to show project A. If user inputs some data then from GET or POST you need to replace `where p.name = 'A'` A with that user input value. If you want to display data for all the projects then just remove the where condition.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you want?

```
select 
    p.Name as Proj, 
    (select sum(time) as TotalDur from EmployeeTimeEntry where proj = p.id group by proj) TotalDur, 
    activity, 
    sum(e.time) as ActivityTime 
from Projects p
inner join EmployeeTimeEntry e on e.proj = p.id
where p.Name = 'A'
group by name, activity, p.id
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee1fa/1)